# How do Memory Mapped Files behave on certain Crash Scenarios?

Tags: linux

If I understand memory mapped files correctly a memory mapped file is flushed to disk randomly or on sync. Also if the buffer is shared one can expect random flushes.

Anyhow when a flush occures and the computer crashes the flush might only be partial done.

If I remember the linux file system (ext4) correctly it gurantees that only a block is written in a atomic fashion. Is there any additional guarantee when it comes to memory mapped files? I mean the block is written guarantee comes from the way the fat is working and that the pointer is written and switched by a single byte write (if I remember correctly).

Does anyone know something about the flush behavior of memory mapped files when it comes to different crash scenarios?